# Attempting to compare values in a list to a string to determine if they match

Tags: python, string, comparison

I am attempting to compare the values within a string to values in a list. If the values match, a third list is addended with either a 1 or 0.

Current attempt is to examine each value within the 2 strings. If the entries within the string match, a hash mark is tallied in a third string (0 or 1). I am unable to make the comparison function work - It's not returning any values.

[Recent edit:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmZe4.png) I cannot link to the assignment page, but i can post an image of the problem.

Code is below:

```
> #list values
landing_outcomes =['True ASDS      41\nNone None      19\nTrue RTLS      14\nFalse ASDS      6\nTrue Ocean      5\nFalse Ocean     2\nNone ASDS       2\nFalse RTLS      1\nName: Outcome, dtype: int64']

> #string values
bad_outcomes = {'False ASDS', 'False Ocean', 'False RTLS', 'None ASDS', 'None None'}


landing_class = []


> #comparison
if any (x in [landing_outcomes] for x in [bad_outcomes]):
landing_class += 0

else:
landing_class += 1


print (landing_class)
```

Comment: `if any (x in [landing_outcomes] for x in [bad_outcomes])` landing_outcomes is already a list.  You don't need the extra `[ ]` around it.  Same for bad_outcomes.

Comment: If you just change `landing_outcomes` to a string (rather than a list containing one string) then you can use `in` to check whether any bad outcome is in that string. (After you remove the extra `[ ]` brackets as @JohnGordon states.)

Comment: To clarify the above comments: `landing_outcomes` is a `list` with a single string element, which doesn't seem like what you intended.

Comment: `landing_class += 0` Also, that is not the right way to add zero to a list.

Comment: Thank you for all the rapid responses. I will try to explain further - I want to see if the the values in bad_outcomes are present in Landing_outcomes. I will have to read up further on bracket usage.

Comment: Is `landing_outcomes` actually a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Also, the exercise wants you to iterate through `landing_outcomes` and check if each row is in the set `bad_outcomes`. The reverse of your question.

Comment: Landing_outcomes was pulled from a dataframe. It beleive it is a list.      How would check to see if bad_outcomes is in landing_outcomes - if statement is reversed maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit (the image you added)...

- `landing_outcomes` is a pandas Series (A column from a dataframe)
- the index of which is the list of Outcomes
- you want to check the dataframe against the set
- which is the opposite of your question

```
import pandas as pd

landing_outcomes = pd.Series(
  [41, 19, 14, 6, 5, 2, 2, 1],
  index=['True ASDS', 'None None', 'True RTLS', 'False ASDS', 'True Ocean', 'False Ocean', 'None ASDS', 'False RTLS'],
  name='Outcome'
)

bad_outcomes = {'False ASDS', 'False Ocean', 'False RTLS', 'None ASDS', 'None None'}

print() 
print(landing_outcomes)
print()
print(bad_outcomes)

landing_class = (~landing_outcomes.index.isin(bad_outcomes)).astype(int).tolist()

print()
print(landing_class)
```

That Series object has an `isin()` method that returns a new Series with True or False on each row.

Using `~` inverts the boolean values (so giving the result of "is not in").

Casting a boolean to an integer (with `astype`) turns those booleans in to 1s and 0s.

Then `tolist()` turns the pandas Series into a regular python list.

Demo; https://onecompiler.com/python/3yvw2dc7b